# Disable DOM size managment in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

According to the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html), all ajax pages fetched are removed from the DOM on pageHide. Is there a way to disable this functionality? It is causing my pages to show a loading screen upon refetching that I am trying to avoid, and the size of the site is fairly small. Thanks!

Comment: This is the default behavior that jQuery Mobile exhibits when you navigate away from a pseudo-page. user1228295's answer describes how to disable this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the docs on the page you referenced:

> To keep all previously-visited pages in the DOM, set the domCache option on the page plugin to true, like this:
>
> $.mobile.page.prototype.options.domCache = true;
>
> Alternatively, to cache just a particular page, you can add the data-dom-cache="true" attribute to the page's container:
>
> <div data-role="page" id="cacheMe" data-dom-cache="true">

However it does seem odd that you're getting a loading message, it's not something I've had with jQueryMobile. Are you loading pages over a slow network?

Comment: +1, a good reminder that reading the documentation fully goes a long way.